# How to get multiple refs to use the same handleClick function?

Tags: reactjs

I have a few similar elements:

```
 <div ref={this.ref1} onClick={this.handleClick} className="icon-wrapper"></div>
 <div ref={this.ref2} onClick={this.handleClick} className="icon-wrapper"></div>
 <div ref={this.ref3} onClick={this.handleClick} className="icon-wrapper"></div>
```

In my constructor, I declare these refs:

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.ref1 = React.createRef();
    this.ref2 = React.createRef();
    this.ref3 = React.createRef();

}
```

I'm trying to pass these refs to their respective `handleClick()` functions. Something like:

```
 <div ref={this.ref1} onClick={this.handleClick(ref1)} className="icon-wrapper"></div>
```

or

```
 <div ref={this.ref1} onClick={this.handleClick(this.ref)} className="icon-wrapper"></div>
```

And I'm trying to handle the ref in the `handleClick` function like this:

```
handleClick = (ref) => {
    console.log(ref);
}
```

And just as a ridiculously wild guess, I tried:

```
handleClick = () => {
    console.log(this.ref.current);
}
```

That all seems dead wrong because `onClick={this.handleClick(ref)}` would invoke the function immediately, which is not what is wanted from a click function.

How do you pass different refs to the same function so that the function knows who called it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is you are invoking the function immediately. Thats what applying `()` does to the end of a function. Instead you need to pass a callback function that needs to be invoked by the event. This is done by passing the function reference.

You can use `bind` here if you need to pass a value. `.bind` will return a new function to be invoked. `null` as the first argument is for the `this` context, null wont change its context assuming its already been bound to your class. If you need to bind this method you can just pass `this` through instead of `null`.

I would recommend passing something to map though instead of the whole ref, like so

```
<div ref={this.ref1} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, 'ref1')} className="icon-wrapper"></div>
```

then you would access like so

```
handleClick = (ref, event) => {
    if (!this[ref]) return
    console.log(this[ref].current);
}
```

Most use cases for passing a parameter to your function would be because you need a specific key. In this case it looks like you just want to access the element itself. You can get that from the event itself.

```
<div onClick={this.handleClick} className="icon-wrapper"></div>

handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

Comment: This is not type safe

Comment: care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is to use a lambda method,

```
 <div ref={this.ref1} onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.ref1)} className="icon-wrapper"></div>
 <div ref={this.ref2} onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.ref2)} className="icon-wrapper"></div>
 <div ref={this.ref3} onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.ref3)} className="icon-wrapper"></div>
```

But if what you want to do is to access the target that fired the event, you can use

```
handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
}

<div onClick={this.handleClick} className="icon-wrapper"></div>
```

Edit: Here are some alternatives with better (marginal) performance.

```
handleClick1 = () => this.handleClick(this.ref1)

handleClick1 = this.handleClick.bind(this, this.ref1)

render() {
  return (<div ref={this.ref1} onClick={this.handleClick1} className="icon-wrapper"></div>)
}
```

Comment: Lint standards recommend to avoid inline lambdas. Performance differences are negligible unless the lambda is applied to a parent component that has a lot of children. Just as a fyi :). Regardless +1 from me :)

Comment: It's the same with binds.

Comment: no actually `.bind` is about 2x more performant. Let me see if i can find the performance result study about this :)

Comment: Function components make this irrelevant though. Who uses classes anymore. Even Gaeron said that he uses lambdas at Facebook.

Comment: Lol @ that statement. I use classes and functional components, depending on the use case.

Comment: Sure, but if you have a component with multiple state items, sometimes class syntax is less verbose :) as one example. I personally prefer writing more explicit code. And typescript because its amazing haha